# In my spreadsheet and start entering into a cell, if a cell above contains a similar entry, the cell auto fills, how can I change the properties?

Tags: microsoft-excel

In my spreadsheet and start entering into a cell, if a cell above contains a similar entry, the cell auto fills, how can I change the properties?

It's like predictive text on your phone, the system checks all cells above the one you are entering into and if it finds a partial match will auto fill the cell.

I am having a problem in which the system is searching downward and as the cells are blank will not find a match.

How can I change it to search upwards as it should be?

Comment: You have two quite different questions here. Please edit your question to focus on a single question.

Answer (score 2):

As explained [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/turn-automatic-completion-of-cell-entries-on-or-off-0f4aa749-b927-4ea7-adaa-86f8d4f9fe20#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20stop,this%20option%20on%20or%20off.):

> Microsoft Office Excel completes text entries that you start to type in a column of data — if the first few letters that you type match an existing entry in that column. If you want to stop automatic completion, you can turn this option off.
>
> 1. Click File > Options.
> 2. Click Advanced, and then under Editing options, select or clear the Enable AutoComplete for cell values check box to turn this option on or off.